Is this a conforming implementation if a later executed operation precedes the earlier executed one in the modification order?
Consider this example:
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
int main(){
    std::atomic<int> v = 0;
    std::thread t1([&](){
        if(v.exchange(1,std::memory_order::acq_rel) == 2){ // #1
            std::cout<<"t1\n";  // #2
        }
    });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(24 * 60 * 60)); // #3
    std::thread t2([&](){
        if(v.exchange(2,std::memory_order::acq_rel) == 0){ // #4
          std::cout<<"t2\n";  // #5
        }
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

In this example, #3 makes #4 be executed after #1, in the timeline. The argument of #3 means that #4 is executed after 24 hours later. From the perspective of the C++ standard, Is it possible that we see the following outcomes?
t1

t2

That is, t1 is first printed, and t2 will be printed 24 hours later
Or, it can be
t2

t1

That is, t2 and t1 will both be printed 24 hours later. In such two outcomes, #4 precedes #1 in the modification order of v.
Can a conforming implementation theoretically have such two outcomes? That is, a later executed operation in the timeline is ordered before the earlier executed operation in the modification order of the atomic object.
Updated:
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::atomic<int> v = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0;i < 2;i++) {
        int index = 0;
        std::cin >> index;
        std::cout << "input " << index<<"\n";
        std::thread t([&, index]() {
            const int condition = index == 1 ? 2 : 0;
            if (v.exchange(index, std::memory_order::acq_rel) == condition) { // #index
                std::cout << "t" << index << "\n";
            }
            });
        threads.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    for (auto&& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}


"#3 makes #4 be executed after #1" -- there is no such requirement. It's highly likely, but not required. It's up to the OS to schedule threads. From a C++ language perspective, those two threads and their side effects are completely independent.

There is nothing that requires #4 to execute after #1. The execution of #1 can be delayed 24 hours. For example, the process might get suspended immediately after the sleep is issued to the OS but before the first lambda starts (because it takes time to create an OS thread). When the process resumes, the two thread lambdas are now racing.

General rule: Expect no thread synchronization that you didn't code yourself or was explicitly called out in the documentation.

Mind you, it's also quite easy to screw up synchronization, so the previous comment needs a rider that the synchronization you coded yourself (and that of the implementation) must be correct.

A conforming implementation is still conforming if you attach a debugger and single-step each thread with arbitrary delays.
Or for example set breakpoints right before the calls to std::cout << and let them proceed in either order once both threads have reached the breakpoints.  Or just set a breakpoint on the std::cout<<"t1\n"; statement, then continue some time after the t2 string has been printed.
And/or breakpoints before the if statements, since they need to run in a particular order for their conditions to be true.

The "reasonable" and "finite" time guarantees for visibility of atomic stores to atomic loads are only "should" not "must" because of possibilities like this, or extreme system load, or a process or system being suspended / resumed, etc.  The intent is that C++ implementations shouldn't make the best case worse than it needs to be, and shouldn't introduce infinite / unbounded delays (e.g. by compile-time reordering operations across potentially infinite loops).  In real implementations, the normal case is just up to the hardware, where if you try really hard you might make it take a few microseconds for a load to see a store, instead of the usual tens of nanoseconds inter-core latency when both threads are running on different cores. (e.g. store buffer full of cache-miss stores that have to commit before this one.)
But ISO C++ absolutely does not give any kind of real-time worst-case latency guarantee, so no, a 24 hour sleep (#3) does not guarantee that #4 is "scheduled" after #1.  (Or that there isn't an arbitrary delay between the atomic operation and the std::cout<<.)
Depending on what kind of program you're writing, it might be reasonable to rely on some very loose real-time guarantees, like that no thread will "starve" for more than an hour.  Especially if the downside of being wrong isn't corrupting a database or something, but rather just spurious output or just wasted work.
If targeting an embedded system running a real-time kernel with controlled hardware and software, you might have pretty tight real-time guarantees, like that thread creation will take at worst a few milliseconds for the kernel to reclaim some memory if necessary.  And that there won't be so many threads running that your new thread can't run right away.


Can [...] That is, a later executed operation in the timeline is ordered before the earlier executed operation in the modification order of the atomic object.

ISO C++ says nothing about how modification order is established. Or about time when individual statements are executed. So you'd have to invent a definition for what you mean when you say an atomic RMW is "executed".
It very likely comes down to question of semantics, whether you mean "start attempting" or you mean "actually make progress", e.g. by doing the store side of an exchange.
In terms of purely ISO C++ without considering real CPU behaviour, it seems to me like a pointless question whose answer wouldn't help you understand anything or design better but still correct algorithms.
But in terms of real CPUs, yes, possible even there for sensible definitions of execution time for an RMW.
An RMW LL/SC loop can start executing, e.g. run ldrex and have it send out a request for exclusive ownership of the cache line, but a couple clock cycles later an LL/SC on another core (which already owned the cache line) could start and finish successfully, doing an RMW on the same object before that core even saw the RFO request.
Actually, that could happen even on x86 or ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomic RMWs. The response to its RFO will have the second core's modification, so an LL/SC on the first core could just succeed, not needing to retry.  So that's an even stronger definition of having "started" than just having attempted an LL but where the SC will fail.
I'm picturing a simplified case where a multi-core ARM CPUs has all its cores running on the same clock, so it's easy and sensible to talk about time between cores separately from memory visibility and ordering.  (This is normally a bad idea when thinking about algorithm correctness: there are basically zero constraints on actual timing, just ordering.  Think about inter-thread communication like putting a letter in the mail; recipients will see it when they see it, and wishing for anything else is just going to cause you problems.)
Anyway, it can happen on real CPUs that C++ can target, so it's clearly allowed by ISO C++ without even getting weird.  At low enough clock speed (e.g. in a slow simulation of a physical CPU design), a few clock cycles could take 24 hours if you want.  (Often a cycle-accurate or electrical simulation would be of a multi-GHz system, so "real time" inside the guest would also run slowly and 24 hours would still be trillions of guest cycles.  But it doesn't violate anything in the C++ standard to do it differently.)
There are other ways for atomic RMWs to work, too, like "remote" atomics where a CPU core just sends a request to L3 cache for the operation to be done there, without ever needing to get a consistent copy of the cache line to the core.  I think PowerPC has had this for a while.  Intel proposed it with their RAO-INT atomics, that would be very weakly ordered (and not return a result, so only useful for stuff like incrementing an event counter, something OSes often need to do.  It doesn't matter which core sends out a request first, it matters what order they arrive and are processed at the relevant slice of L3 cache, or memory controller, or whatever's doing it.

@PerterCordes From the perspective of the C++ standard, given a hypothetical implementation, if #4 is executed 24 hours later than #1, is it still a conforming implementation if #4 instead precedes #1 in the modification order of v? Assuming the delayed time is not caused by breakpoints or similar things. after all, 24 hours is a reasonable finite time.

I also updated the example to make the question clearer. Each input will create a new thread. The first time, inputting 1 to create t1, then 24 hours later, inputting 2 to create t2, can the RMW operation in t2 precede that in t1 in the modification order, in a hypothetical conforming implementation from the view of the C++ standard?

@xmh0511: Why would it matter if the delay comes from attaching a debugger or not?  You mean so memory-reordering effects become possible, unlike on a real CPU where taking a breakpoint is a full barrier?  So maybe a PowerPC clocked at a few Hz, built for real or in a simulator.

@xmh0511: ISO C++ says nothing about how modification order is established.  Or about time when individual statements are executed. So you'd have to invent a definition for what you mean when you say an atomic RMW is "executed".  It very likely comes down to question of semantics, whether you mean "start attempting" or you mean "actually make progress", e.g. by doing the store side of an exchange.  Seems to me like a pointless question whose answer wouldn't help you understand anything or design better but still correct algorithms.

@xmh0511: On real CPUs, it's definitely possible for an RMW LL/SC loop to start executing, e.g. run ldrex and have it send out a request for exclusive ownership of the cache line, but a couple clock cycles later an LL/SC on another core (which already owned the cache line) could start and finish successfully, doing an RMW on the same object before this core even saw the RFO request.  (Assuming for simplicity that all cores run at the same clock speed.)  If the clock speed is low enough, that could be 24 hours.

«Why would it matter if the delay comes from attaching a debugger or not?» The debugger essentially makes such two RMW operations executed by the CPU at a close time. Although the modification order is irrelevant to the timeline, I'm not sure whether this understanding is completely right. I just constructed this example to ask the confirmation of this concept only from the theoretical perspective.

«So you'd have to invent a definition for what you mean when you say an atomic RMW is "executed".» I meant the instruction corresponding to the RMW operation had been executed by the CPU at that time. So, mean "actually make progress", e.g. by doing the store side of an exchange. this is actually what I meant for "executed".

@xmh0511: I just updated my answer with an example of it being possible on real CPUs, with a detailed-enough definition of "executed" to be usable.  Your definition of "executed by the CPU at that time" is not usable; if you mean finished executing, then that could include committing the RMW's store to cache, which would mean it's too late for anything to come earlier in the modification order.  You're basically asking of an RMW can start executing, but another RMW can start later and finish executing first.  So you need detailed definitions of what you mean by that.

@xmh0511:  by doing the store side of an exchange. - then no, not on a CPU that works anything like the ones we use (MESI cache coherency).  When that store commits to cache, that's when this value is established as the next modification after the one loaded by the RMW.

«When that store commits to cache, that's when this value is established as the next modification after the one loaded by the RMW.» However, in my example, what #1 wrote was based on the value 2 which is written by #4, so #4 preceding #1 in MO does not violate anything, even if #1 was first committed to the cache, right?

«if you mean finished executing, then that could include committing the RMW's store to cache, which would mean it's too late for anything to come earlier in the modification order.» Since MO does not grow incrementally by the timeline, an RMW operation that happened first in the time is ordered after(in the MO) the RMW operation that happened later, which is still conforming to what the C++ standard says, even though the result is counter-intuitive.
